# Can I drill or notch a 2x2 bottom plate in a flat-stud wall?

Tags: framing

Trying to get low-voltage cables from the basement to the attic, the best route goes through a utility closet framed with a flat-stud wall on two sides (the third side is an exterior wall which I would prefer to avoid). The bottom plate is a 2x2 sitting on top of the floor.

I can't find any mention in the building code here in Seattle about limitations on drilling or notching of bottom plates, only of studs and top plates. Should I take that silence as an indication that it's okay to drill or notch as much as I want of the 2x2 bottom plate in order to bring the cables through? Would removing a entire piece of the bottom plate be an option?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bottom plates typically don't carry any load. You can feel free to drill as needed there. Really, you could remove an entire section of the plate and probably not encounter code violations. Drywall will span gaps of 4-6" without a problem, assuming it's protected from impacts.